# How can I debug native code using Visual Studio EXPRESS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx-9, slimdx

I'm working on an application that uses a managed wrapper of the DirectX API. My IDE is Visual Studio C# 2010 Express. I need to be able to debug the DirectX API calls, however, the 'express' version of Visual Studio C# 2010 does not allow for the debugging of native code. How can I see the output of the DirectX API?

Answer (score 0):

There are application available such as [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx) which will monitor debug output. Simply download DebugView and run the program and it will capture the native debug output.